# Add new column based on conditions and the value difference of other column

Tags: sql, oracle

I think I might be overlooking something obvious here. I'm not asking someone to write the whole code for me, I just need a hint or a link to a similar case.

My query:

```
select Client , ProductID, M_POS_TYPE AS Keep_or_Keep_in_Transit, Amount
FROM inventory_table inv_table
JOIN inventory_position inv_pos
ON inv_pos.ProductID=inv_table.ProductID
group by Client, ProductID, M_POS_TYPE, Amount
```

Output:

[image]

How can I add a new column that checks if the the subtraction of the values in the column: `Amount` is different from 0 for same `ProductID` and `Client`?

Desired:

```
5-4<>0
```

> THEN

(Y)

[image]

What I have tried to use is conditionals, `CASE` statement, but how can I make sure it will calculate the difference for the same `Client` and `ProductID`?

I'm looking for a solution in the generic case, there are thousands of different ProductsIDs and Clients values in the table. I'm a bit stuck in this problem.

Comment: You only need this when rows with "Keep" and "Keep_transit" are **both** present? That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. CUSTOMER2 has only "Keep" but no "Keep_Transit"; for most if not all real-life cases, you would not consider that "Keep" and "Keep_Transit" amounts are equal (since one of them doesn't even exist in the first place). Please clarify. Note that this has nothing to do with programming of any kind - it's all about the problem description.

Comment: Hi mathguy, right. My bad. I've removed the rows where Keep_Transit /Keep have 0 as value. Keep and Keep_Transit always exist. The post was edited. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you only asked for a tip or hint. Without example or test with data and only as short explanation.
Google for "Analytic Functions" that could help you to solve it. So you can sum up per client, ProductID and then compare in a CASE.

Maybe something like this.

```
select Client , ProductID, M_POS_TYPE AS Keep_or_Keep_in_Transit, Amount,
sum(case when M_POS_TYPE = 'Keep_Transit' then AMOUNT*-1 else AMOUNT end) over (partition by Client, ProductID) as DIFF
FROM inventory_table inv_table
JOIN inventory_position inv_pos
ON inv_pos.ProductID=inv_table.ProductID
```

Hope you get ahead with it.

Comment: you can remove the group by since it is not required in this case

Comment: Ich hab es drinnen gelassen, weil Lorenzo es drinnen hatte. Vielleicht braucht er es, weil es nur ein Teil des SQLs war. Aber ja, du hast Recht, es könnte raus.

Comment: many trhanks for the calrification and the post